# SpringBoot : Consul Health indicator missing from the Health endpoint

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have a SpringBoot based web application that exposes a consul health indicator bean.
The bean is correctly created and initialized by springboot's autoconfiguration, yet, the indicator is not showing in the actuator health endpoint despite the fact that the associated configuration property "management.health.consul.enabled" is set to true:

```
{
   "status": "UP",
   "components": {
        "Kafka": {...},
        "SchemaRegistry": {...},
        "discoveryComposite": {...},
        "diskSpace": {...},
        "ping": {...},
        "refreshScope": {...}
    }
}
```

Upon further inspection, I found the bellow snippet that is responsible for fetching all the available indicators ([HealthEndpointConfiguration.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.java#L81)) :

```java
    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    HealthContributorRegistry healthContributorRegistry(ApplicationContext applicationContext,
            HealthEndpointGroups groups) {
        Map<String, HealthContributor> healthContributors = new LinkedHashMap<>(
                applicationContext.getBeansOfType(HealthContributor.class));
        if (ClassUtils.isPresent("reactor.core.publisher.Flux", applicationContext.getClassLoader())) {
            healthContributors.putAll(new AdaptedReactiveHealthContributors(applicationContext).get());
        }
        return new AutoConfiguredHealthContributorRegistry(healthContributors, groups.getNames());
    }
```

Setting a break point there, I see that indeed the ConsulHealthIndicator bean is not listed in the output of the *applicationContext.getBeansOfType(HealthContributor.class)* call as shows bellow :

[image]

But when I test the same call with the parent application context instead, I get the following :
[image: AnnotationConfigApplicationContext]

Can someone please shed some light on why this particular bean is present in the [root context](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.html) but not in the [child context](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/web/servlet/context/AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext.html) ?

Is there a way to force it's initialisation in the child context so that it will get correctly registered in the health endpoint ?

I'm currently using

- SpringBoot 2.3.1.RELEASE
- spring-cloud-starter-consul-all 2.2.4.RELEASE

Thank you in advance.

---

### EDIT

I've attached [a sample project](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-consul/files/5101952/consul-integration-sample.zip) allowing the reproduction of the issue.
I've also included an the consul configuration that is used by the app (you can import it via consul import command).
Running the example above and going to the health endpoint (localhost:8080/monitoring/health) you will clearly see that the consul component is missing from the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get the consul indicator working, I had to supply my own HealthContributorRegistry where I take into account the parent context when performing the HealthContributor beans lookup :

```java
  @Bean
  HealthContributorRegistry healthContributorRegistry(
      ApplicationContext applicationContext, HealthEndpointGroups groups) {
    Map<String, HealthContributor> healthContributors =
        new LinkedHashMap<>(applicationContext.getBeansOfType(HealthContributor.class));
    ApplicationContext parent = applicationContext.getParent();
    while (parent != null) {
      healthContributors.putAll(parent.getBeansOfType(HealthContributor.class));
      parent = parent.getParent();
    }
    return new DefaultHealthContributorRegistry(healthContributors);
  }
```

This is a temporary workaround, ideally the consul indicator should be working out of the box like the rest of the health contributors.